# How to use Bootstrap validator to validate file size and file type

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I`m using Bootstrap validator ([Validator plugin](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#)) to validate my form but I have an input for files which I would like to have a custom validation for filetype and filesize (pdf,docx,doc..).

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <label class="input-group-btn">
       <span class="btn btn-primary">
Browse&hellip; <input type="file" style="display: none;" name="cv" required data-filesize="5242880" data-filesize-error="Max 5MB">
       </span>
     </label>
     <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
     </div>
</div>
```

I need some directions on how I should use this plugin in order to validate the input on my frontend before the backend runs its own validation.

Comment: The link you gave is broken

Comment: @Ish Fixed it. Thank You!

Comment: @Daniel I switch to [this plugin](http://parsleyjs.org), for me it fit better. If you like, here is an example of custom validations: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/customvalidator.html

Answer (score 2):

Code from [here](http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/validators/file/) worked for me:

```
<form id="fileForm" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Avatar</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="avatar" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileForm').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            avatar: {
                validators: {
                    file: {
                        extension: 'jpeg,png',
                        type: 'image/jpeg,image/png',
                        maxSize: 2048 * 1024,
                        message: 'The selected file is not valid'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example extracted from: [https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/73](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/73#issuecomment-240320633)

```js
$('form[data-toggle="validator"]').validator({
  custom: {
    filesize: function ($el) {
      var maxKilobytes = $el.data('filesize') * 1024
      if ($el[0].files[0].size > maxKilobytes) {
        return "File must be smaller than " + $el.data('filesize') + " kB."
      }
    },
    
    //custom file type validation
    filetype: function ($el) {
      var acceptableTypes = $el.prop('accept').split(',');
      var fileType = $el[0].files[0].type;
     
      if (!$.inArray(fileType, acceptableTypes)) {
        return "Invalid file type"
      }
    
    
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/dist/validator.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="well">
  <form data-toggle="validator">

    <div class="form-group form-group-file">
      <input type="file" id="file1" name="file" class="form-control" data-filesize="5000"
             data-filetype="application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/rtf"/>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good example. Do you have any idea why when you try to select a file the window won't show other files then PDFs? The validation looks like it passes DOC and DOCX. `data-filesize="5000" accept="application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/rtf" />`

Comment: @Daniel it's because of the `accept` attribute of the file input. I just updated the example with a custom file type validation. To build your custom validations take a look here ("custom" option): http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-options

Comment: http://jsbin.com/riwajanuxu/1/edit?html,js,output  It works as intended. The only problem is that if you try to submit this form with no file attached then it will just send the form. Without errors

Comment: Fixed it I just had to verify if the object exists like this: `if ($el[0].files[0] && $el[0].files[0].size > maxKilobytes) { }`